# CType and Type casting Exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapp

```
Public Property Duration() As Integer
Get
  Try
    Return CType(Item(DurationColumn), Integer)
  Catch e As Global.System.InvalidCastException
    Throw New Global.System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column 'Duration' in table 'T_MembershipSale' is DBNull.", e)
  End Try
End Get
Set(ByVal value As Integer)
  Item(DurationColumn) = value
End Set
End Property
```

What happens when a user wants to allocate `""` as `Item(DurationColumn)` to integer? I get an exception. Any clean solution to avoid this and set `0` for `""`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx):

```
Dim number as Integer
If Not Int32.TryParse(DurationColumn, number) Then number = 0
return number
```

This handles the case of "", as well as any other invalid value (i.e. non-number) the user might enter.

Comment: To me, this is the clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `TryCast` and `Int32.TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsNumeric`

```
    number = If(IsNumeric(DurationColumn), CType(DurationColumn, Integer), 0)
```

Comment: That won't work.  According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1.aspx, "IsNumeric  will also return True if the string being checked is a number containing a comma or a dollar sign". It also returns True if it's a floating-point number or a number that's larger than will fit into an integer (i.e. a Long or ULong).

Comment: @Jim Mischel, issue described is check for "", not for overflow or something else. I understand your point but this snippet of code does actually work

Answer (score 0):

You could assign function return to variable first then check variable before conversion.

```
    Dim sRet As String = Item(DurationColumn)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sRet) Then Convert.ToInt32(sRet)
```